# How do you make javascript echo all the data whilst in a SQL while loop?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, pdo

So im trying to do a timer for my script but it only counts down the last result instead of all of them and for all the results that return from the query all show a countdown from the last result. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
<?php 
$q = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM pending_payments WHERE user_id = ? AND status = ?");
$q->bindParam(1, $session_id);
$q->bindParam(2, $pending);
$q->execute();
if($q->rowCount() > null){
?>                      
                        <h4 class="title"> Pending Payment </h4>
                        <div class="squiggly-border"></div>
                        <table class="table table-index">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th>Item</th>
                                    <th>Expires</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
<?php
while($r = $q->fetch()) {
$pending_payment_id = $r['id'];
$pending_item = $r['item'];
$pending_expiry = $r['expiry'];
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = <?php if($dateUNIX < $pending_expiry){ echo $pending_expiry - $dateUNIX; } ?>;
var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

function timer() {
    count = count - 1;
    if (count == -1) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        return;
    }

    var seconds = count % 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    minutes %= 60;
    hours %= 60;

    document.getElementById("pEFTimer<?php echo $r['id'] ?>").innerHTML = hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes "; // watch for spelling
}
</script>                           
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text"><?php echo $pending_payment_id; ?></td>
                                    <td class="text"><?php echo $pending_item ?></td>
                                    <td class="text" id="pEFTimer<?php echo $r['id'] ?>"></td>
                                    <td class="text"><a href="pendingPayment<?php echo $r['id']; ?>" ><button class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Proceed to Payment</button></a></td>
                                </tr>
<?php
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
}
?>
```

Comment: use console.log(someoutput) to get the output.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I dunno if ive placed it in the incorrect place but could you show me an example of how you would add the console.log

Comment: You can output your PHP as a Javascript variable (array).

Comment: @Milkmannetje Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

In javascript functions are variables that execute some code, so basically instead of creating a function for every row, what you are doing is updating the function to only track the last element.

Let's be clear of the places where each language works, PHP outputs your html in the server, the html is parsed by the browser and after that Javascript is executed in the browser (client side).

This being said, the best approach to solve this is that you should store the data in the HTML as a data attribute on an specific element of each row, retrieve this with JavaScript, and then start a timeout that updates all the elements at the same time.

Comment: I can see what your saying but wont that slow down the page?

Comment: Not at all, maybe 10 or 15 years ago. But with modern browser, their JavaScript machines ara amazingly fast.

Comment: I attempted it but i failed miserable. would you be able to show me how you would do it. Thanks (Im still relatively new to programming)

Comment: Does anyone else know how to do what @Ramy Deeb is talking. Im still struggling